# ImportError with startup script for Google Cloud Compute

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I get an ImportError with startup script for Google Cloud Compute. I believe there is something wrong with permissions and/or SSH. My program runs fine from the SSH console. In the start-up script, it gets an import error. I've tried putting the full path, partial path etc. This is the debug output. My startup script is cd, then python path/to/file.py. Ubuntu 1604 xenial v20190212.

```
startup-script: INFO Starting startup scripts.
startup-script: INFO Found startup-script in metadata.
startup-script: INFO startup-script: Traceback (most recent call last):
startup-script: INFO startup-script:   File "Project/analyzePDFs.py", line 6, in <module>
startup-script: INFO startup-script:     from _mongoWrite import w_db, r_db, f_db
startup-script: INFO startup-script:   File "/home/davidxmkong/Project/_mongoWrite.py", line 1, in <module>
startup-script: INFO startup-script:     from pymongo import MongoClient, UpdateOne, InsertOne
startup-script: INFO startup-script: ImportError: No module named pymongo
startup-script: INFO startup-script: Return code 1.
startup-script: INFO Finished running startup scripts.
```

Comment: Are you installing pymongo as part of the startup script? Assuming it's a new VM it would need to be installed if it doesn't come default. When you say it works with SSH, is that on a fresh VM?

Comment: Pymongo is already installed

Comment: Can you provide your startup script for further details? Also, what OS image are you using for your VM?

Comment: Updated question!

Comment: Startup scripts do NOT have your user context. This is not correct `/home/davidxmkong`. Put your program someplace else and do not assume details about environment variables, PATHS, etc.

Comment: Interesting, I will try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to install all the dependencies on the root.
So I did sudo su, then reinstalled python, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar issue where my startup script was pretty much only

python3 myscriptname

The issue was that when the startup script ran python3, it referenced a different installation of python3 than the one I installed all my modules on. So I qualified the python3 (in my case /opt/conda/bin/python3) and the ImportErrors went away.